# How do I retrieve an array of arrays of arrays in Julia?

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, readlines

I am new in Julia, so don't judge me please (ha ha)

This is my situation: I needed to save several 2x2x2 matrices whose elements were vectors of 4 elements, but now when I try to retrieve them from a file, I can't !!!

This is what I did:

To create these matrices I made this function

```
function InitialConf(L_=2,S_=2,T_=2,Dim_=4)
  Conf_=Array{Array{Float64,1}}(L_,S_,T_)
  for i_ = 1:L_, j_=1:S_,k_=1:T_
    Conf_[i_,j_,k_]=RanUniVec(Dim_)
  end
  return Conf_ 
end
```

Where *RanUniVec(Dim_)* is the function that creates these vectors of 4 dimentions with special characteristics that are not important for this discussion:

```
function RanUniVec(Dim_)
  vector_=Array{Float64}(Dim_)
  while true
    for i_ in 1:Dim_
      vector_[i_]=UniformRand(-1,1)
    end
    if norm(vector_)<1 && norm(vector_)>0.5
      break
    end
  end
  vector_=normalize(vector_) # 2-norm
  return vector_ 
end


function UniformRand(a_,b_)
  rand_=(b_-a_)*rand()+a_
  return rand_
end
```

I needed two of these matrices (for example) so I did the next:

```
States=[]
Conf1=InitialConf()
Conf2=InitialConf()
push!(States,Conf1)
push!(States,Conf2)

f=open("Info.txt","w") do f
    write(f,"$States")
end
```

This made the *Info.txt* file where is my information, but when I try to get the *States* array again from this file, Julia tells me that it can't

```
f=readlines("Info.txt")
States=parse(f)

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching parse(::Array{String,1})
Closest candidates are:
  parse(::Type{IPv4}, ::AbstractString) at socket.jl:167
  parse(::Type{IPv6}, ::AbstractString) at socket.jl:218
  parse(::Type{DateTime}, ::AbstractString, ::DateFormat{Symbol("yyyy-mm-dd\\THH:MM:SS.s"),Tuple{Base.Dates.DatePart{'y'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'m'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'d'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'H'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'M'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'S'},Base.Dates.Delim{Char,1},Base.Dates.DatePart{'s'}}}) at dates/parse.jl:202
```

...

Do you know how I can get again my *State* array?

Comment: If you check `methods(parse)`, you'll note Julia does not have a method for parsing a string to an array (of any type). You could define one yourself, but TBH storing an `Array{Vector{Float64},3}` in a text file is a fairly odd choice. Why not just use `JLD2` or `HDF5` packages? They are much better suited to storing arbitrary types.

Comment: I've just found out the existence of those packages, but the problem is that I have several of these files in that format and it took me days to make them (omg!!). And I don't know how to make that kind of method.

Comment: I have another doubt too: if I try to make just one of these arrays of vectors, for example: `julia> Array{Float64,1}[[0.642831, -0.549382, -0.202601, 0.493864] [0.0309127, -0.677569, -0.734793, 0.00480957]; [-0.921989, 0.296193, -0.228128, 0.100814] [0.00511441, 0.633875, -0.770675, -0.0650897]]` It gave me an error again. if I could jump this error I think I could make something...

Comment: I would strongly recommend re-doing your analysis but use `JLD2` or `HDF5`. You are just digging the hole deeper otherwise and will have to write all sorts of very customized text parsing routines which run very slowly. Honestly, I don't know of *any* programming language that has built-in methods for reading and writing arrays of any dimension higher than 2 to text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should use Colin's recommendation from the comment in the long run. Here is what you can do if you actually have those text files already generated. I will use a smaller example.

Assume your original array is consisting of two 2x2x2 arrays. Here is an example I will use:

```
julia> z
2-element Array{Array{Int64,3},1}:
 [1 2; 3 4]

[10 20; 30 40]
 [1 2; 3 4]

[10 20; 30 40]

julia> z[1]
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 10  20
 30  40

julia> z[2]
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 10  20
 30  40
```

Now it will get saved to a file as the following string:

```
julia> repr(z)
"Array{Int64,3}[[1 2; 3 4]\n\n[10 20; 30 40], [1 2; 3 4]\n\n[10 20; 30 40]]"
```

And parsing this string will clearly fail. What you have to do is to edit your files to add `cat` method invocation on each entry of a big array and pass dimension `3` as the one on which you want to cat them.

This means that from the original contents of the save file:

```
Array{Int64,3}[[1 2; 3 4]

[10 20; 30 40], [1 2; 3 4]

[10 20; 30 40]]
```

You have to make this file contain:

```
Array{Int64,3}[cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40]),
               cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40])]
```

Those changes can be done either by hand or you could write a program to perform the transformation (you have to replace `,` by `), cat(3,`; `\n\n` by `,`; make sure that first `cat` and last `)` are added as they will not be caught by the first two rules).

Now if you read it in it as a string you can evaluate result of parsing it:

```
julia> s = """Array{Int64,3}[cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40]),
                          cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40])]"""
"Array{Int64,3}[cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40]),\ncat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40])]"

julia> eval(parse(s))[2]
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 10  20
 30  40
```

Note, however, that all this is not recommended - it is better to use the packages that Colin recommended to do this.

Comment: Actually I implemented the same idea (but at hand and using Vim, not so automatizated ). Lesson learned. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your specific question, but a general recommendation for future development. To save data to disk, and reload later, give preference to formats such as `JLD2.jl`.

You save with

```
@save "filename.jld2" ARRAY
```

and load with

```
@load "filename.jld2" ARRAY
```

without having to figure out what was the format you chose in the past. Saves a lot of headache with complex data structures.